# Xamarin.Forms Ellipse draws a rectangle rather than an ellipse

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm at XF 5.0.0.2012...

Whenever I try to use the new ellipse element, it just draws a rectangle no matter what I try. Has anyone else had this issue? I'm seeing this on iOS. My project doesn't have an android project to compare with.

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                        <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="50"></Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

Comment: have you tried using it in a layout other than a grid?  Or just as the content of a ContentPage?

Comment: So far I've just tried it inside a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `BackgroundColor` with `Stroke`, (or `Fill`), more details in [ellipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/ellipse)

```
        <Ellipse
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            WidthRequest="50"
            HeightRequest="20"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Stroke="White"
            StrokeThickness="2" />
```

Plus, you can do `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions` like this in XF5.0:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="4*, 6*" RowDefinitions="*, *, *, *, *, *">
```

Comment: Worked.  And thanks for the tip on Column/Row definitions. What a huge improvement!